# Having problems with txn_date Between over a 24hour period broken up into two 12 hour chunks

Tags: sql, database, sql-scripts

I currently have a data pull that tracks data from 0730-1930 and 1930-0730.  Data refreshes at the start of each time period.  My problem is my script stops pulling a half hour early; it ends at 0700 and 1900 instead of 0730 and 1930.  Copy below:

```
z0.txn_date Between (CASE WHEN To_Number(To_Char(SYSDATE,'hh24')) 
Between 7 AND 7+12-1 Then TRUNC(SYSDATE) + 7/24 WHEN 
To_Number(To_Char(SYSDATE,'hh24')) Between 7+12 AND 23 Then 
TRUNC(SYSDATE) + (7+12)/24 ELSE TRUNC(SYSDATE) - 1+ (7+12)/24 END) 
+ (0.5/24) AND (CASE WHEN To_Number(To_Char(SYSDATE,'hh24')) 
Between 7 AND 7+12-1 Then TRUNC(SYSDATE) + (7+12)/24 WHEN 
To_Number(To_Char(SYSDATE,'hh24')) Between 7+12 AND 23 Then 
TRUNC(SYSDATE) + 1 + 7/24 ELSE TRUNC(SYSDATE) + 1 + 7/24 END) + 
(0.5/24)
```

I have tried various forms of adding .5 to different sections, but this always breaks the script.

Comment: format your code, please, and tag with database

Comment: what database you are using?

Comment: We are using a Xeus database.